# Pip freeze shows a weird version of a package

Tags: python, pip, freeze, requirements.txt

So I was creating the requirements.txt file by using the command :

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

and one of the packages had this as a version :
setuptools==52.0.0.post20210125

Why is this so?
And will this give an error when I deploy my project on a cloud platform.

Comment: It's not so weird: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme . If you use virtualenv, prefer use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Corralien pointed out it's not that weird to have a post-release version of something: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme

Post-releases are usually made to make some minor change to the released package that does not affect the code necessarily (e.g. a typo in the readme, or some other minor packaging bug).

It *is* a little weird in this case because on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#history) there is no `52.0.0.post20210125` release for setuptools.  There is, however, a [51.1.0.post20201221](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/51.1.0.post20201221/) release which was apparently [made by mistake](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2500).

I don't know how you ended up with the one you have though.  It does not appear to exist (maybe it was deleted).

You should try upgrading setuptools before freezing your pip environment since the one you have is outdated anyways.

Answer (score 2):

From a virtualenv:

```sh
$ pip list --format=freeze > pip_list.txt

$ pip freeze > pip_freeze.txt

$ diff pip_list.txt pip_freeze.txt
```

```
84d83
< pip==21.1.3
124d122
< setuptools==57.1.0
```